# why setOnClickListener not working in adapter with recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

> i m just simply implementing setOnClickListener to adapter same setOnClickListener was working one day ago and
>
> same issue i met with few days ago but i made anothers adapter and it did the trick but again today i met same problem
>
> though i googled but did get the answer and i m posting here question to what could be the reason i meet often where i m making mistake and keep this in mind for further codes.

**adapter class**

```
 package "";

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.Youtubedownloader.R;
import com.android.Youtubedownloader.activities.CustomPlayer;
import com.android.Youtubedownloader.database.Model;
import com.tonyodev.fetch.Fetch;
import com.tonyodev.fetch.request.RequestInfo;

import java.util.List;

import static com.android.Youtubedownloader.service.AppService.fetch;



public class ViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewAdapter.Holder> {

    private List<Model> list;

    public ViewAdapter(List<Model> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new Holder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final Holder holder, final int position) {
        final Model model = list.get(position);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (model.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                    if (!model.getFilePath().equals("") && model.getFilePath() != null) {
                       /* Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(model.getFilePath()));
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(model.getFilePath()), "video*//*");*/
                        Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), CustomPlayer.class);
                        intent.putExtra("path", model.getFilePath());
                        holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "file not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title, percentage, downloaded;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        ImageView pause, resume;
        LinearLayout bottom;
        View itemView;

        //   TextView textView;

        public Holder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.itemView = itemView;
            //   textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
            percentage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_percentage);
            downloaded = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_downloaded);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            pause = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_pause);
            resume = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_resume);
            bottom = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bottom);
        }
    }  
}
```

**adapter item xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/img_app"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/margin_5">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_download"
                    android:tint="@color/youtube" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_percentage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="0%" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bottom"

                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_app"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/video_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:text="video title" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:progress="100" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_downloaded"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:text="downloaded:" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_pause"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/youtube"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_pause_circle_filled_white_24dp"
                    android:tint="@color/white"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_resume"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/youtube"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_play_circle_filled_white_24dp"
                    android:tint="@color/white"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**update**

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("click", "click working");
            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "file not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (model.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                if (!model.getFilePath().equals("") && model.getFilePath() != null) {
                   /* Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(model.getFilePath()));
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(model.getFilePath()), "video*//*");*/
                    Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), CustomPlayer.class);
                    intent.putExtra("path", model.getFilePath());
                    holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "file not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
```

**update xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i would be better if down voter explain it'

Comment: this code is just fine onclick listener will work in this condition.
please check your if condition.

Comment: @anddevmanu but its not working

Comment: add log in your listener before if condition and after if condition so that you know the result

Comment: @anddevmanu tried but not working

Comment: Please provide code how you tried with log

Comment: @anddevmanu see update

Comment: send your xml code of recycler view
i think your are consuming your click event somewhere.

Comment: @anddevmanu see update xml

Comment: don't use setOnClickListener in onBindViewHolder it is not a good approach let me share a piece of code with you just copy paste and try

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"it doesn't work"_? does it crash? it doesn't crash but you do not get the result you want?

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem. After many tries then I noticed that xml attributes somehow disables ItemView clickListener. So I remove below codes from layout and it works now.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

absolutely this works good as per my experience.

Comment: Genius.  So odd that Google SDK docs don't instruct to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try below one code

```
public class ViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewAdapter.Holder> {

private List<Model> list;
private Context mContext;//Init Context

public ViewAdapter(List<Model> list,Context _context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.mContext = _context;//getting your activity context
}

@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new Holder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_item, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Holder holder, final int position) {
    final Model model = list.get(position);
    holder.mParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (model.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                if (!model.getFilePath().equals("") && model.getFilePath() != null) {
                   /* Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(model.getFilePath()));
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(model.getFilePath()), "video*//*");*/
                    Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), CustomPlayer.class);
                    intent.putExtra("path", model.getFilePath());
                    holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "file not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//here your using context

            }
        }
    });




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title, percentage, downloaded;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView pause, resume;
    LinearLayout bottom;
    View itemView;
    CardView mParent;

    //   TextView textView;

    public Holder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.itemView = itemView;
        //   textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        mParent = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
        percentage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_percentage);
        downloaded = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_downloaded);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pause = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_pause);
        resume = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_resume);
        bottom = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bottom);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "cardview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

no luck

Comment: see my edited code coz your not getting context of activity where your using adapter

Comment: Always pass Context of activity in adapter constructor

Comment: ?? hilight  the change

Comment: you just replace my code of adapter and i will add comment

Comment: I have added comment

Comment: create chat room and discuss there

Comment: @dont have enough reputation to create chat

Comment: can you share your project on Google drive or github i will fix it and tell you the reason

Comment: i got the reason and the it  is that  i call a method after every two seconds and reset adapt data after every two seconds so view getting zigzag and onclick not getting fires .. now can u tell me how to solve this problem within calling method after every two seconds ?

Comment: ok i will give u give me any personal contact so i can reach u and share code

Answer (score 0):

In Constructor of Adapter, Passing getActivity() worked for Me instead of getContex()

Answer (score 0):

Change update xml from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include [example] of your code and an explanation of how this works and why it is of solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

**ViewAdapter**

```
import com.android.Youtubedownloader.R;
import com.android.Youtubedownloader.activities.CustomPlayer;
import com.android.Youtubedownloader.database.Model;
import com.tonyodev.fetch.Fetch;
import com.tonyodev.fetch.request.RequestInfo;

import java.util.List;

import static com.android.Youtubedownloader.service.AppService.fetch;
 
public class ViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewAdapter.Holder> {

    private List<Model> list;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public ViewAdapter(List<Model> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new Holder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final Holder holder, final int position) {
        final Model model = list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title, percentage, downloaded;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        ImageView pause, resume;
        LinearLayout bottom;
        View itemView;

        //   TextView textView;

        public Holder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.itemView = itemView;
            //   textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
            percentage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_percentage);
            downloaded = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_downloaded);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            pause = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_pause);
            resume = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_resume);
            bottom = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bottom);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     int position = getAdapterPosition();
                     if (listener != null && position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) 
                     {
                         listener.OnItemClick(getItem(position));
                     }
                }
            });
        }
        
    }  
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
       void OnItemClick(ChildActivityList item);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
       this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

**Activity.Class**
In your activity just call adapter and all the if-else condition there

```
adater.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here, I got this error in 2 adapters, but when I removed the below 2 things from XML, then my `setOnClickListener` was working fine in adapters.

```
<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
```

and

```
android:clickable="true"
```